# I can't click the "buy now" button on amazon with Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to make an amazon bot. I am on the last process but I can't click the buy now button with XPath or full XPath.I could find another unique selector because there is no id in that input.

[image]

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
import winsound


options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\QP\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data")


driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:\\webdrivers\\chromedriver.exe", chrome_options=options)
driver.get("https://www.amazon.com.tr/gp/product/9750748468?pf_rd_r=NCJRXGDB60BMBAWHZB0K&pf_rd_p=dbef927e-126e-4d59-a744-316eb26cc421&pd_rd_r=081be57a-efdb-4f6b-b282-72fb528b1bc5&pd_rd_w=Avc97&pd_rd_wg=XdzTG&ref_=pd_gw_unk")
try:
    addCart = driver.find_element_by_class_name("a-button-stack")
    addCart.submit()

    frequency = 2500
    duration = 50
    winsound.Beep(frequency, duration)

    completeTheShopping = driver.find_element_by_class_name("a-button-inner")
    completeTheShopping.click()

    buyNow = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html//body/div[8]/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[1]/span/span//span[1]/span/input')
    buyNow.click()


    print("Item found")

except NoSuchElementException:
    print("Item doesnt exist")
```

Comment: Have you tried reaching the grandparent element with `id=BottomSubmitOrderButtonId` and find the element with the tag 'input' from there?

Answer (score 0):

## This will Solve it

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
import winsound
import time

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\QP\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data")

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:\\webdrivers\\chromedriver.exe", chrome_options=options)
driver.get("https://www.amazon.com.tr/gp/product/9750748468?pf_rd_r=NCJRXGDB60BMBAWHZB0K&pf_rd_p=dbef927e-126e-4d59-a744-316eb26cc421&pd_rd_r=081be57a-efdb-4f6b-b282-72fb528b1bc5&pd_rd_w=Avc97&pd_rd_wg=XdzTG&ref_=pd_gw_unk")
try:
    addCart = driver.find_element_by_class_name("a-button-stack")
    addCart.submit()

    frequency = 2500
    duration = 50
    winsound.Beep(frequency, duration)
    time.sleep(2)
    completeTheShopping = driver.find_element_by_class_name("a-button-inner")
    completeTheShopping.click()
    time.sleep(2)
    buyNow = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="sc-buy-box-ptc-button"]/span/input')
    buyNow.click()


    print("Item found")

except NoSuchElementException:
    print("Item doesnt exist")
```

### How I solved it

You were using the `Full xpath` where as you should have copied the `xpath` and it works now.
And I also added a `time.sleep` delay as it helps if the internet is laggy sometimes.
Hope this Solves the Problem.
And yes I used Edge Driver you may wanna change it back to chrome.
You should copy the xpath like this
[image: Picture Xpath Copy]

Comment: when i was used xpath there was changed nothing and time.sleep(2) didnt work.Thank you so much.

Comment: @UmutPalabiyik You can use `pyautogui` module if you do not want to deal with amazons anti-bot policy.